# How can I select all elements of certain class except those that are children of this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an element that has children with different classes.  How can I select all elements of certain class `.cellDiv` in the DOM, except those that are children of `this`?

Comment: CSS3 has a `not` function. Dunno if jquery supports it though.

Comment: when you say "children" do you really mean it, or do you mean all descendants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
$('.cellDiv').not($(this).find('.cellDiv'))
```

or, if you know that `this` has an id, it should be faster to do

```
$('.cellDiv:not(#' + this.id + ' > .cellDiv')
```

Answer (score -1):

Well a good idea would be to do first an addClass to this like so 
`$(this).addClass('selected');`
then you'll know the this has also class 'selected' then you select all withhout 'selected' class 
`for ....
  if(!$(element).hasClass('selected')){ 
  ... select it ...
}`

Comment: This seems messy to me and to be unnecessary DOM manipulation.

Comment: before CSS3 that was a suitable solution